# Extracting data from an existing plot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I was trying to extract some data from existing plots, I'm using the below code and it works perfectly, however, it seems that the original data are not integers and therefore, I end up getting alot of float datas which I dont need. I tried to use round() function but then I will have repetitave values which is not the required output. I'm not sure whether it's possible, but I was wondering if there's away to extract the values from the plot immediately as integers. below is a small sample of what iam trying to achieve.
any help is much appreciated, thanks!

This is the code:

```
from IPython.display import Image

ax = Image(r'Desktop\comp.png')
ax = plt.gca()
line = ax.lines[0]
x = line.get_xydata()
dataframe=pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['a','b'])
```

This is the image:

[image]

This what I get as a result:

[image]

However, I'd like to get something similar to this result:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to extract the values from a plot, when you have the data available in the dataframe? Is there a situation where you have only a plot, and no raw data (dataframe)? If I understood correctly, you woud like to get the *interpolated* data, interpolated to integer values of `a`. This you can do very easily for example with [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html).

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, actually sometimes I have row datas and sometimes I have only plots and in both cases they're float that's why I thought it would be a good idea to convert them all to plot and try to work accordingly.

Comment: I have also tried to use the interpolate function within the dataframe, but it's not working when I try to set the x column as an index since it's a float! do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I posted an answer, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanx alot, this answer is very hepful! can you please suggest how it can be done directly for a dataframe so I won't have to convert them each time to plots and then re do the same thing!

Comment: Sure! Just replace the beginning, where the data is read from the plot, with `data_x, data_y = df['a'].values, df['b'].values`. (where `df` is the name of your dataframe, and 'a' and 'b' are names of the columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the plot as [matplotlib.axes](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/axes_api.html) object, you can extract the data with [ax.lines](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.1/api/lines_api.html) methods [`get_xdata()`](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.1/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.get_xdata) and [`get_ydata()`](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.1/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.get_ydata)

```
line = ax.lines[0]
data_x, data_y = line.get_xdata(), line.get_ydata()
```

Then, create integer values for the new axis with

```
import math
new_x = range(math.ceil(min(data_x)), math.floor(max(data_x))+1)
```

And interpolate values with [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) to get the corresponding y-values:

```
f = interp1d(data_x, data_y, kind='linear', bounds_error=False, fill_value=np.nan)
new_y = f(new_x)
```

The output as pandas DataFrame would look like this:

```py
In [3]: pd.DataFrame(dict(a=new_x, b=new_y))
Out[3]:
   a          b
0  1   1.022186
1  2   4.899643
2  3   9.032727
3  4  16.073667
4  5  25.066514
5  6  36.888971
6  7  49.033702
7  8  64.018056
```

and as a plot like this:

[image]

#### Full example code

Full example code would look something like this:

```py
import math

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

# Create data for example
data_x = np.array(range(9)) + np.random.rand(9)
data_y = data_x**2

# Create the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
ax.plot(data_x, data_y, marker='s', label='original')

# Extract data from plot (your starting point)
line = ax.lines[0]
data_x, data_y = line.get_xdata(), line.get_ydata()

# Get the x-axis data as integer values
new_x = range(math.ceil(min(data_x)), math.floor(max(data_x))+1)

# Get the y-axis data at these points (interpolate)
f = interp1d(data_x, data_y, kind='linear', bounds_error=False, fill_value=np.nan)
new_y = f(new_x)


plt.plot(new_x, new_y, ls='', marker='o', label='new')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```